# Mudar cor de ícones na API 19 KitKat

Tags: android, desempenho, drawable

Como a API 19(KitKat) ainda é muito popular, é uma boa escolha dar suporte para esta versão. Porém, ela não dá suporte à diversas features, como backgroundTint e ImageTint. Isso me põe em vários problemas de compatibilidade e escolhas de design.

Tenho diversos ícones para carregar em uma tela e atualmente estou usando setImageTintList para fazer a dinâmica do app.

[image: 4 emoticons coloridos e 1 cinza. 1 sinal de dinheiro colorido e 4 cinzas]

As "carinhas" e os "dinheirinhos" devem mudar de cor de acordo com o elemento em uma recyclerView. Qual a melhor forma de dar suporte à essa função em sistemas com API < 21?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso pode ser conseguindo recorrendo às [bibliotecas de compatibilidade](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html).

As bibliotecas de compatibilidade permitem que recursos existentes nas novas versões do android sejam usadas em versões antigas.

Para a [utilizar](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html) deverá baixá-la e adicionar o seguinte

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
```

na secção `dependencies` do arquivo build.gradle.